# How to correctly translate "Every pentagon has something in the same row" to first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm playing around with the Tarski's world application (which is a grid with different shapes of different sizes that can be placed on each of the cells of the grid) and I can't get my translation of the predicate "Every pentagon has something in the same row" to evaluate correctly. My translation is:

$\forall x \exists y (Pentagon(x) \implies SameRow(x, y))$

Here I'm basically saying that if $x$ is a pentagon, then it is always the case that there exists some other shape in the same row as $x$ (or at least thats what I think I'm saying), however when I test this in Tarski's world, the predicate evaluates to True even when nothing else but a pentagon is placed on a row. What is the error here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The predicate evaluates to True even when nothing else but a pentagon is placed on a row. What is the error here?

Note that pentagon itself is also 'something'

It evaluates as true is because the predicate $SameRow$ is taking $x$ as both parameters like:

$$SameRow(x,x)$$

What you think actually is:

$$\forall x \exists y (Pentagon(x) \implies (x\neq y \land SameRow(x, y)))$$

where $x\neq y$ stand for have distinct object.

Comment: thank you, this makes a lot of sense